# Removing metadata from components in generated swagger and their associated $refs in responses

Tags: swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We are using the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package for swagger.  We have a lot of calls that return polymorphic objects such as SortEntry<type> or VersionedObject<type> and it seems that the generated components in the swagger contains a bunch of meta data about these objects like such:

```
"Data.SortEntry`1[[Data.Search.Enums.DetailsSortType, Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
```

Not to get too into the weeds but this is only really a problem due to our process, where we validate the API contract using the generated swagger.  So this metadata causes problems because it contains a version property that will change each time and fail our build.

My question is, is there a way to suppress this metadata that is being generated?  In previous versions of Swashbuckle (<3.0) this was not a problem for whatever reason.

Edit:  Here is an example of what one of these components would look like in back when we were using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.x and generating swagger json v2.0:

```
SortEntry[DetailsSortType]
```

We are using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore @ 5.6.3 and are generating OpenAPI 3.0 swagger.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through some other issues here I ended up find this:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1803

I was able to pull the TypeContext.cs code that was originally available in SwashBuckle.AspNetCore 4.x.x and implement a custom schema id using that.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this file to your project, it's a type extension that returns a "friendly" name for the class:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/TypeExtensions.cs

A type extension lets you attach and call new methods on a class, and you don't even need the original class code or have to recompile, etc. Under the hood a type extension is a static function that accepts the class it's defined on as one of the arguments.

To use it with Swashbuckle & Swagger, just add this line to your StartupBase.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(a => a.CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FriendlyId()));
```